# I need your help whith android studio in the gradle error

Tags: android, firebase, android-appcompat

I want to implement Firebase to my project, but following error don't let me. I need your help.

I'm getting [squiggly lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyvnr.png) on Appcompat Dependency:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

**gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.steven.musica"
            minSdkVersion 24
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example directly in your question along with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you haven't shown your `build.gradle` file, I'm assuming you have updated it as explained in [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) by implementing:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin
```

and Maven Repository

```
maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
}
```

Also, please change this:

`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'`

to this

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'`

**Edit:**
I have added a screenshot to help you better.

Goto `Gradle Scripts > build.Gradle(Project)` and add it what I have highlighted in blue and then click on `SyncNow`

**Note:** Don't change your default `build:gradle:version` as mine is `build:gradle:3.0.1`

Just copy *goole-services plugin* and *Maven Repository* as referenced in the screenshot.

[image: Build Gradle - Project]

Comment: Where does the maven go? in the gadle? and thanks so much for your help

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: loooool thanks so much !!!

Comment: Welcome Esteven! So, I believe your project is working fine now. Best of luck! :)

Answer (score 3):

The libraries appcompat-v7 and support-v7 must have the same version.

In your dependencies you have `appcompat-v7:27.1.1` and hidden into `firebase-core:15.0.0` you have `support-v4:26.1.0`

add `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'` to force firebase-core to use the version 27.1.1